# Create new data frame boolean column based on dynamic number of other columns all being true

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which always starts with a target column, then an unknown number of other columns, all of booleans (results of agrep searches against a dynamic number of search patterns).

I need to create a column called final_result, which is TRUE if any of the boolean columns have a TRUE value in them.  The number of boolean columns is unknown in advance as the data frame is created on the fly.

My rather naive approach was this:

```
target = c('blood', 'pressure','lymphatic')
result_1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
result_2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
# may be many more columns, unknown at runtime

df = data.frame(target, result_1, result_2)
df$final_result <- any(df[,2:ncol(df)])
```

but this returns:

[image: code results]

the last result "lymphatic" has both FALSE values,  and so should return FALSE.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = rowSums(across(-target)) > 0)

#>      target result_1 result_2   new
#> 1     blood     TRUE     TRUE  TRUE
#> 2  pressure     TRUE    FALSE  TRUE
#> 3 lymphatic    FALSE    FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that does not require any additional packages is:

```
df$final_result <- apply(df[,-1], 1, any)
```

The `-1` means all of the columns except the first one.  The `apply` function will convert the rest of the data frame into a matrix, then apply the `any` function to each row (the 2nd argument is 1 for rows, 2 for columns).

Another approach that does not convert to a matrix (so could be faster in some cases) is:

```
df$final_result <- Reduce(`|`, df[-1])
```

This treats the data frame as a list and starts by finding if the first column (after dropping "target") **or** the second is `TRUE`, then finds if that result **or** the third column is `TRUE`, then compare that result with the 4th column, on until it runs out of columns.

If you want to use the tidyverse, then `pmap` from the `purrr` package can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df$final_result <- df[-1] %>% pmap_lgl(any)
```

For any of these you can replace the `-1` with `2:ncol(df)` or with the results of `which`, `grep`, `sapply` etc. used to select columns.

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, we can use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(final_result = if_any(starts_with('result')))
```

-output

```
      target result_1 result_2 final_result
1     blood     TRUE     TRUE         TRUE
2  pressure     TRUE    FALSE         TRUE
3 lymphatic    FALSE    FALSE        FALSE
```